# How display progress message/bar when a backend process is running?

Tags: java, progress-bar

I use Runtime.getRuntime().exec to run a perl program. Now I want to display a percent progress bar during the execution and then after the execution of perl program is finished, it should close the progress bar. How can I do it?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec (perl.exe, test.pl);

progress bar code?
```

Please help.

Comment: How do you know how far the process has completed?  Is it output it's own progress?  Or do you just want an infinite wait style progress?

Comment: Basically, the perl program runs in background and does image comparison and produces image diff. So I don't know how to configure progress bar read output.

Comment: Unless the script outputs so e kind of information, there's no way you can display a progress, unless you want to display an indeterminate progress bar

Answer (score 2):

You have several options.

You can create a progress bar that is 'Indeterminate' which is the style that just keeps going and going until you stop it.

You can read the output from the program you a running as the values to set for the progress bar.

Or you can use a Progress Monitor which will predict how long the operation is going to take.

You can check then all out [here with the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) on using progress bars.